# Custom EAV admin form enabled websites in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, eav, adminform

I'm dealing with a custom EAV, I build all the admin part (grid and form), but now I would to implement the website abilitation like in products entity, like the following screenshot.
[image]

Someone can give me some hint to reproduce this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when I try to implement a feature that is also done elsewhere in Magento, the most obvious part to start looking is at the source of Magento itself.

I'd suggest looking at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Websites.php` where the `modifyMeta()`-method is used to add the field to the form in the admin.

I also see `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/websites.phtml`, but I believe that's used elsewhere (see `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_action_attribute_edit.xml` for more information on that one).

Next up is saving the data accordingly, but that answer lies also within the code.

Comment: of course, I've wached at this code, but I have to understand the use of modifiers and attach to my EAV